# could not call class method from another class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to eclipse and Java.Please find the code below.I have created maven project in eclipse.But i could not call a method from the class which is in another package.Please find the code .But this code works fine in netbeans.

```html
FILE 1 : 

package config;
public class ActionKeywords {
 
  
         public static void helo( )
         { ............
  }
}

FILE 2 with another package:

package executionEngine;
import config.ActionKeywords;
public class driver{
 
   
    ActionKeywords.helo(); /////////////ERROR //////////
         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
obj_Actionkeywords.helo();
```

with this:

```
Actionkeywords.helo();
```

Also put this call in a method!

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Actionkeywords.helo();
}
```

Comment: But you need to put the call in a method!

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to call a stataic method, you do not need an object instance but call the method directly like:

```
public void myMethod() {
    ActionKeywords.helo();
}
```

Read more about static fields and methods here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: this is not working.tells that " Syntax error on token "helo", Identifier expected after this token"

Comment: Then it seems to be another problem. Please show your full code of method helo()

Comment: When I use CTRL + SPACE after putting dot ,complier says that no default proposals.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is that you are trying to call ActionKeywords.helo(); right in a class. This is not possible, you need to call it in a method. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Yes, it is callable anyway, it will just not do anything of course. See my updated answer above and try it like that.

Comment: I did not downvote your question. It's okay to be a new to something ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As `helo` is `static`, it is good practice to call it using  a static modifier:

```
ActionKeywords.helo();
```

instead of using an object reference.

Comment: this is not working.tells that " Syntax error on token "helo", Identifier expected after this token".

Comment: It works for me, but not when I write `ActionKeywords.helo();` outside of a method, because Java thinks that you meant a class field which is not correct syntax ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Object reference name is obj. Why the call is made using obj_Actionkeywords?
As its a static method, u can use class name itself.

ActionKeywords obj= new ActionKeywords();
obj_Actionkeywords.helo();

Comment: this is not working.tells that " Syntax error on token "helo", Identifier expected after this token"

Comment: Call it inside a method.. for ex: public static void main (String[] args){
    ActionKeywords.helo(); 
   }

Answer (score 1):

Your call `obj_Actionkeywords.helo();` is wrong.
It should be `obj.helo();`
or since helo is static it can also be `Actionkeywords.helo();`. By the way this should go in some method of the class driver. **Try to read some java tutorial first :)**

Answer (score 0):

`helo()` is a static method of `ActionKeywords` class.

All static method can access without creating object and we can access static method directly by `<class-name>.methodName();`

so you can try like

```
  ActionKeywords.helo();
```

Comment: Sasi, Please understand the Question.

Comment: After your edit, nothing wrong in your code so check it again

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has auto-complete feature. So, in your Eclipse IDE, type "ActionKeywords." and wait. Do you get helo() method listed automatically? If not remove the import statement and try to type "ActionKeywords". Highlight the mouse on ActionKeywords which should prompt you with import statement. Import accordingly and the type the ".helo()" part. Since the code works fine on Netbeans, the only problem I could think is your import statement.

Comment: Also, in your code public class driver{
 
   
    ActionKeywords.helo(); /////////////ERROR //////////
         
}            You are calling the method helo() directly within a driver class instead of calling it in a method inside driver class. Strange how this code would work in Netbeans because method invocation would not occur from a class directly irrespective of IDE.